# Text Categorization using R

Tags: r, text-mining

I am relatively new at using R. I have a dataset of around 5000 datapoints. 
My goal is to predict a category using the comments entered. 
I have a training dataset of 4500 records and a testing data set of 500 records. 
I am looking for 2-3 packages which might help me in doing this.I have to evaluate these packages and prepare a report on that. Can anyone suggest me some good packages which might easier to use and also more efficient.

Again, I have 2 columns 
1st one is comments and based on this I have to predict the category. 
Right now I have defined around 10 independent categories.

Most of the comments have specific keywords which I have defined as categories

One such example
Comment 1 
The website is pretty good --->> category would be WebsiteContent

comment 2 might be like

Excellent article ,very detailed--->> same category as above(WebsiteContent)

But the keywords such as article, website are very limited and can be linked to the category

all of comments are different but the underlying keywords are mostly the same

Thanks, 
Ankan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad, but you might start with looking at a bag of words approach and the package `tm` to build document vectors.

Comment: You're problem statement is very poorly defined.  Think a bit more about what you are trying to do and please try it yourself.  If you still have a problem, please give a reproducible example.  If I were to venture a guess: it looks like all you need to use is an ifelse statement.

Answer (score 0):

Although all you need is a very long and well written set of `if-else` statements, try using a Decision tree from the package from the `rpart` and `prp` package. I'm saying this only cause you're trying to learn and I'm guessing this is for some assignment which you're supposed to be doing on your own.

```
tree<-rpart(train$decision~train$comment, method"class")
prp(tree)
```

The first line builds the model and the second one plots it. This might be a bit overboard actually but since you're learning R this is a fun thing to work with and can be used for a wide variety of things. Although, Decision trees work better with more predictor variables.

Use `predict(test,tree)` to test out the model on your test dataset.

Comment: For some reason I can't install the package 'prp' (error code-  package ‘prp’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)) . Is there any alternate package for this?  I have created the training and testing dataset as            train_idx <- sample(1:nrow(DataSet),1200,replace=FALSE)
train <- DataSet[train_idx,] # select all these rows
test <- DataSet[-train_idx,]                                                                                    ..

Comment: The dataset has 2 columns comments and category .. for the training dataset the categories are available... My question is how do I train my algorithm or the decision tree? .. I tried looking up online but couldn't find anything

Comment: The first line I put in is used to train your dataset. Creating a model is the same thing as training a model. Also, please update your version of R.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am currently using a small dataset of 1000 data points and whenever I am running the command - tree<-rpart(train$decision~train$comment, method="class"). RStudio gets stuck with connection failed issue and the R console is also taking lot of time and is still running. How long does it generally take to create the model.